# Calculate and Output a checkbox in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, checkbox, boolean

Currently, I'm using `apex:inputCheckbox` and feeding it a boolean value from the controller with a dedicated variable since the Value attribute in the `apex:inputCheckbox` cannot have a formula expression.

Example:

```
<tr>
    <td> Info </td>
    <td> <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!isCurrent}" disabled="true" /> {!current.Name} </td>
    <td> <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!isPrevious}" disabled="true" /> {!Prev.Name} </td>
</tr>
```

The problem with the above approach is, I have around 30 checkboxes and I need to have a dedicated variable for each in the controller.

What I'd like to do is, to calculate true or false within Visualforce using formula expressions.

```
<tr>
    <td> Info </td>
    <td> <span class="checkbox"> {! NOT(ISNULL(current.Text__c))} </span> {!current.Text__c} </td>
    <td> <span class="checkbox"> {! ISNULL(current.Text__c)} </span> {!Prev.Text__c} </td>
</tr>
```

Is it possible to output a checkbox without using the `<apex:inputCheckbox>` component in Visualforce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a normal "input", but it's pretty painful. Here's what it would look like:

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(current.Text__c))}">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" />
</apex:outputText>
<apex:outputText rendered="{!ISNULL(current.Text__c)}">
  <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" />
</apex:outputText>
```

You might want to just consider writing a VF component so you can consolidate the logic:

```
<c:outputCheckbox checked="{!NOT(ISNULL(current.Text__c))}" />
```

The component would look something like this:

```
<apex:component >
    <apex:attribute name="checked" type="Boolean" default="false" description="checked state" />
    <apex:outputText rendered="{!checked}">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" />
    </apex:outputText>
    <apex:outputText rendered="{!not(checked)}">
        <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" />
    </apex:outputText>
</apex:component>
```

Comment: I considered this approach. But hoping for a simple solution. The task sounds ridiculously simple. But implementation is very complex. I'll wait for some time if anybody has a better solution and mark this as answer if not.

Comment: I did end up going this route.